# Updating fragment textView text from adapter class after removing a list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment with a recyclerView.

There is textview in the fragment that shows the number of items from the recyclerView.

At every recyclerView item is a button to remove the item from the recyclerView:

In adapter:

```
subjects.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRangeChanged(position,subjects.size());
```

where subjects is the list that populates the recycleview.

These three lines do remove the item from the recyclerView and update the list size.

What I need is to update at the same time the textview from the fragment which is showing the number of items in the recyclerview, passing the new value from subjects.size() to the fragment as text for the textview.

EDIT

```
public class RecyclerViewFollowingMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewFollowingMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<UsuariosBuscarFollowing> subjects;
public RecyclerViewFollowingMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(List<UsuariosBuscarFollowing> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();

    this.subjects = getDataAdapter;

    this.context = context;



}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_amigos_following_busqueda, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
```

Fragment. Adapter initializing:

```
txtNumFollowers.setText(numFollowers+" "+getResources().getString(R.string.followers));


        recyclerViewadapterFollowers = new RecyclerViewFollowersMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(subjectsListFollowers, getActivity());
        recyclerViewFollowers.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterFollowers);
```

Comment: provide a code for adapter and fragment.

Comment: show me your adapter constructor and how you initialize the adapter.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam, I will update my question and include my adapter code

Comment: and the method in which you create that adapter.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam, done

Comment: cant see the code where you initialize the adapter from the fragment.

Comment: @HasanBouTaam, done, included textView that should change its text from the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start by creating an interface in new file in your project**

```
public interface onItemRemovedFromListListener{

void onItemRemoved(String text);
}
```

**in your fragment**

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment implements onItemRemovedFromListListener{



//pass the listener to the adapter

........
recyclerViewadapterFollowers = new RecyclerViewFollowersMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(subjectsListFollowers, getActivity(),this);
recyclerViewFollowers.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapterFollowers);

}

@override
public void onItemRemoved(String text){

//update your text view
txtNumFollowers.setText(text);

}


}
```

**in your adapter**

```
//include a new field for listener
........
private onItemRemovedFromListListener listener;
.......

//constructor

public RecyclerViewFollowingMiosBusquedaCardViewAdapter(List<UsuariosBuscarFollowing> getDataAdapter, Context context , onItemRemovedFromListListener listener){

    super();

    this.subjects = getDataAdapter;

    this.context = context;

    this.listener = listener;



}

//now when you remove item from adapter notify the listener the fragment method will fire

subjects.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
notifyItemRangeChanged(position,subjects.size());

//send text to update
listener.onItemRemoved("the text that you want to update goes here");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have implemented all your code and works like a charm.!!!! NIce tutorial for interface integration.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use your subjects list as a live data

```
LiveData<List<Subject>> subjects = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

Then observe your list and listen to the changes. And when you get the new list update UI according to your textView.

```
   subjects.observe(this, subjects -> {
       // update your textView here

        });
```

Comment: I need to update a textView text not from the adapter itself, but from the fragment with the recyclerview

Comment: ok. if you listen your LiveData list, when you call subjects.remove, subjects.observe trigged and you can update wherever you want

Comment: I can update my list definition as you propose using LiveData, but how to update the text in the fragment textVIew?

Comment: Your list and this method should be in your fragment. You have to pass it in your adapter with your constructor or your set method. According to this your observe method should be in your Fragment with the same place in your textView

Comment: I am not able to follow your proposal